# react.js react-select onselected value change another select value and submit multiple items to array

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have stomped on a problem that i don't know how to resolve.
I have a react-select input that passes a selected value to another select input.
When a user clicks on submit button then i have to display an array of every selector input that the user has selected as a list of items and then the form should reset all select values.
For this, i have tried submitting to an array but it only shows one item from all selectors and form doesn't reset its values.
Here is a sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-carson-i99g8p?file=/src/App.js
How can I archive this I have tried everything but I could not figure out how can i archive this functionality.

Comment: Can you add sample code? The link you provided sent me to an empty project.

Comment: It works on my side

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First tricky thing of react-select is, the value you assign to the component must be an object with `label` and `value`properties, not just the value. Meaning, when handling change events, you should set the state using the full `event` object.

This is the code mostly fixed:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";
const options = [
  { value: "0", label: "0" },
  { value: "1", label: "1" },
  { value: "2", label: "2" }
];

const options2 = [
  { value: "Before Due Date", label: "Before Due Date" },
  { value: "After Due Date", label: "After Due Date" }
];

const App = (props) => {
  const [numOfDays, setNumOfDays] = useState('');
  const [beforeDueDate, setBeforeDueDate] = useState('');

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const [reminders, setReminders] = useState([]);

  const submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent form submit action

    const obj = {};
    obj.id = reminders.length + 1;
    obj.numOfDays = numOfDays.value;
    obj.beforeDueDate = beforeDueDate.value;

    setReminders((items) => [...items, obj]); // <-- update arr state

    setBeforeDueDate("");
    setNumOfDays("");
  };

  function numOfDaysHandle(event) {
    // const numOfDays = event.value;
    setNumOfDays(event);
    setItems((items) => [...items, items]);
  }

  function beforeDueDateHandle(event) {
    // const value = event.value;
    setBeforeDueDate(event);
  }

  const removeReminder = (id) => {
    setReminders(reminders.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <div>
          {reminders.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>
                <span>
                  {item.numOfDays} days {item.beforeDueDate}
                </span>
                <button onClick={() => removeReminder(item.id)}>
                  removeItem
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div>
          <Select
            options={options}
            value={numOfDays}
            id="numOfDays"
            placeholder="Days"
            isSearchable={false}
            //onChange={numOfDaysHandle}
            onChange={numOfDaysHandle}
          />

          <Select
            options={options2}
            value={beforeDueDate}
            id="beforeDueDate"
            placeholder="Before Due Date"
            isSearchable={false}
            onChange={beforeDueDateHandle}
          />
        </div>

        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Select
              options={options}
              value={item.numOfDays}
              id="numOfDays"
              placeholder="Days"
              isSearchable={false}
              onChange={numOfDaysHandle}
            />

            <Select
              options={options2}
              value={item.beforeDueDate}
              id="beforeDueDate"
              placeholder="Before Due Date"
              isSearchable={false}
              onChange={beforeDueDateHandle}
              //    onClick={() => setItems((items) => [...items, items])}
            />
          </div>
        ))}

        <button
          onClick={submit}
          //disabled={!numOfDays}
        >
          Set Reminder
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please see if you can move forward now, I could not understand what you want exactly with the array of `<Select />` elements.